# ‘Not as simply’ versus ‘not as simple’

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

In [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581782/can-i-pass-a-block-as-a-selector-with-objective-c/4581830#4581830), an editor changed my sentence:

> Not as simply as that, unfortunately.

to:

> Not as simple as that, unfortunately.

The original question was:

> Is there any way to get the following to work?

I used the adverb form because I wanted to convey ‘it is possible, although not *in a manner as simple as* the one described in your question’. I understand that the adjective form used by the editor is correct, but is the adverb form incorrect or unusual?

Comment: I think the editor was wrong to change your text, but I can see how he might have misconstrued it, because it is so far from the question.

Comment: I think grammatically speaking the question doesn't really connect with *either* answer, and to be honest I can't think of a reasonably short way to paraphrase either. The best I can come up with is that the editor's version stands in for *"[The way to get it to work is] not as simple as [the way it's currently implemented]"*, which converts to *"[It's] not as simple as [that]"*. Any paraphrasing using the word *simply* would probably be much more convoluted.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm, I see what you mean. Would ‘You can’t solve it as simply as you are expecting’ be correct? I do agree that ‘It’s not as simple as that’ is probably what the editor meant and likely the best choice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't know what you mean. "Is there any way to get xxx to work?" "Not as simply as that" seems to me to be grammatical, consequential, and natural.

Comment: @Colin: With **simply**, I don't see what "that" refers back to in the original question, so grammatically it falls down for me. With **simple**, I just assume an omitted "It's" at the start of the reply, standing in for *the way to get the following to work*. I'm guessing whoever editted OP's original text was thinking along much the same lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine. Using *simple* means

> Not as simple as the method

while using *simply* means

> Not as simply as how the method works.

Comment: I think both are at least "sloppy". But at least the editor's version is easily salvaged by adding/assuming **"It's"** in front.